# Angular route guard: how to use next available route?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

My routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'specified-module/:moduleName',
        component: SpecifiedModuleComponent,
        canActivate: [ModuleGuard]
    },
    // + routes for another modules
    {
        path: ':moduleType/:moduleName',
        component: ModuleComponent
    },
];
```

The second route should apply for all modules which are unavailable to activate or don't have own component. Unfortunately when some module has its own route and `ModuleGuard` returns `false` then the second route is not being matched for the route anymore.

Assuming: I want the route `specified-module/example` to invoke `ModuleComponent` in case when `canActivate: [ModuleGuard]` returns `false`.

Example of `ModuleGuard` for this question's needs:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModuleGuard implements CanActivate {
    public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it work by default and how can I achieve it?

Comment: The guard is a simple return telling the router if navigation is allowed to that route or not, and doesn't redirect otherwise. You Will need to import / use the router to force a new navigation event.

Comment: Do you mean I should `this.router.navigateByUrl(state.url);` in `ModuleGuard`? It causes a loop...

Comment: Not Quite. Rather than `this.router.navigateByUrl(state.url)` you would want to route to a new route, not that in the state object. I.E. `this.router.navigateByUrl(<INSERT':moduleType/:moduleName'>)` But you would need to work out the moduleType and moduleName here to pass them in.

Comment: But I can't change the route parameters, it has to remain exactly the same...